# How to change the stroke placement of the grease pencil in the UV window?

Tags: uv, grease-pencil

[image]

I want the lines to be fixed in a position not to the view, but every time I start drawing the stroke placement mode changes automatically from cursor to view.

Comment: this is wrong :c,I did not explain myself clearly. My problem is that even after I switch the mode from view to cursor when I start drawing it changes automatically from cursor mode to view mode and it cause me problems because when I zoom out the lines are not fixed to a position in relation with the UV but in relation to the view.
I basically want to draw a box around uv island to know which places are used already even if not everithing is visible.

Comment: @ferson, you can edit your own question to make it clearer - comments like these (this one, and yours) are not to further elaborate but for us to ask questions and get you to update your question with more information if we need it.

Answer (score 1):

After a loooooong time I figured out, I don´t know if it is a bug or something else.

Basically I need to select an image to be able to use the *CURSOR* for stroke placement, if no image is selected the stroke is automatically changed to *VIEW* when you try to paint something[image]